# Construct object (Rectangle) without arguments when __init__ of class requires parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on an assignment that requires a `Rectangle` class that computes the area and perimeters given. We are given the main() function already and have to build around it. It seems to run up until it gets to `b = Rectangle()` where it says it

> requires exactly 3 arguments.

Here is my code:

```
class Shape(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def area():
        pass
    def perimeter():
        pass

class Rectangle(Shape):

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        Shape.__init__(self)
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def area(self):
        area = self.height * self.width
        return area

    def perimeter(self):
        perimeter = 2*(self.width+self.height)
        return perimeter

    def getStats():
        print "Width:      %d" % b.width
        print "Height:     %d" % b.height
        print "Area:       %d" % b.area
        print "Perimeter:  %d" % b.perimeter

def main():

    print "Rectangle a:"
    a = Rectangle(5, 7)
    print "area:      %d" % a.area()
    print "perimeter: %d" % a.perimeter()

    print ""
    print "Rectangle b:"
    b = Rectangle()  
    b.width = 10
    b.height = 20
    print b.getStats()

main()
```

How to get the second rectangle to work without changing the main function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read on python's support for [default arguments](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html) for "constructors"... Something like

```
   def __init__(self, width = 0, height = 0)
```

Comment: Alright, that at least got it to run. I'm getting the output for rectangle A, but rectangle B is giving me this:   <bound method Rectangle.getStats of <__main__.Rectangle object at 0x05728610>>

Comment: @user3550590 Have you tried to search for error to find any information? http://www.bing.com/search?q=phyton+bound+method

Comment: Thanks for the help, actually got it working how it's supposed to now =)